# What is the the correlation between U and V?

Tags: probability

[image]

Given that cov(U,V)=0.001039, find the correlation of U and V where:

X=8U+7

Y=6V+6

Example working:

correlation = cov(x,y)/sqrt(var(x)vary))

My answer is $\dfrac{0.001039}{\sqrt{(0.0050171875)(0.021030555\ldots}}$

var(U) = E(U^2) - E(U)^2 = (((1-7)/8)^2(1st row)+ ((2-7)/8)^2(2nd row)+((3-7)/8)^2(3rd row)) - ((((1-7)/8)(1st row)+ ((2-7)/8)(2nd row)+((3-7)/8)(3rd row)))^2 same for var(V) but instead we use the columns....

And my answer doesn't seem right... i double checked my calculations many times

Comment: This is not a "do my homework for me" site. Please show us your effort, and where are you stuck.

Comment: Now, please tell me what you think about my answer? Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 1):

The first step is to compute the expectation of the product $XY$.  To do this, simply write the corresponding value of $XY$ alongside all of the probabilities in the table; e.g., $$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|} \hline & y=1 & y=2 & y=3 & y=4 \\ \hline x=1 & 1(0.05) & 2(0.10) & 3(0.10) & 4(0.01) \\ \hline x=2 & 2(0.15) & 4(0.25) & 6(0.20) & 8(0.05) \\ \hline x=3 & 3(0.01) & 6(0.03) & 9(0.04) & 12(0.01) \\ \hline  \end{array}$$  Then multiply each value of $XY$ with its probability, so the first cell for $x = 1$, $y = 1$ gives $1(0.05) = 0.05$, and so forth.  Then add together all of the cells.  This gives you $\operatorname{E}[XY]$.

The second step is to compute the marginal distributions.  This is done by adding up the row and column totals:  $$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|} \hline & \color{green}{y=1} & \color{green}{y=2} & \color{green}{y=3} & \color{green}{y=4} & \\ \hline \color{red}{x=1} & 0.05 & 0.10 & 0.10 & 0.01 & \color{red}{0.26} \\ \hline \color{red}{x=2} & 0.15 & 0.25 & 0.20 & 0.05 & \color{red}{0.65} \\ \hline \color{red}{x=3} & 0.01 & 0.03 & 0.04 & 0.01 & \color{red}{0.09} \\ \hline & \color{green}{0.21} & \color{green}{0.38} & \color{green}{0.34} & \color{green}{0.07} & 1\\ \hline \end{array}$$ Now we compute $$\operatorname{E}[X] = \color{red}{1(0.26) + 2(0.65) + 3(0.09)}$$ and $$\operatorname{E}[X^2] = \color{red}{1^2 (0.26) + 2^2 (0.65) + 3^2 (0.09)},$$ and similarly for $Y$ and $Y^2$.  Then the correlation is given by $$\operatorname{\rho} = \frac{\operatorname{E}[XY] - \operatorname{E}[X]\operatorname{E}[Y]}{\sqrt{\operatorname{Var}[X]\operatorname{Var}[Y]}},$$ where $\operatorname{Var}[X] = \operatorname{E}[X^2] - \operatorname{E}[X]^2$ for example.

Comment: I followed all these steps closely and tried literally 100 times. But I am still getting the wrong results/

Comment: @Tree What are the values of $\operatorname{E}[XY], \operatorname{E}[X], \operatorname{E}[Y], \operatorname{E}[X^2], \operatorname{E}[Y^2]$ that you obtained?

Comment: And after you get these, then you can compute the corresponding values for $U$ and $V$ using the linearity of expectation.